# Passing mouse and keyboard events to children of JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jsplitpane

I have a working JPanel extended class that handles all the mouse and keyboard events. I put that panel into a JSplitPane with another JPanel. Now none of my mouse and keyboard events are firing off in my original JPanel.

My theory is that the JPSplitPane now takes the events. Is there a way to easily make it so those events are passed down to my JPanel just  like before?

Comment: I think your theory is not quite right.  If you are using a `KeyListener` for example, it will only register key events when the component it is attached to has keyboard focus AND is focusable.  `MouseListener` will only react to mouse events if the mouse event has a clear track to it, that is, if you have components ontop of your panel which are registered as to listener as `MouseListener`s, they will block your component from receiving mouse events.  But since you've provide absolutely no code to demonstrate what you are doing, that's all guess work

Comment: Agreed with MadProgrammer. The panel probably just doesn't have focus, tho it's hard to tell exactly without the code in question.

Comment: How do you give that panel focus? I click on it multiple times, hit tab, etc, and can't seem to give that panel focus.

Answer (score 0):

Upon my research I found out that the mouse events are handled by the first possible MouseListener (in this case the JSplitPane) so all I had to do was this...

```
splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,leftColumn, analyzerPanel);
splitPane.addMouseListener(analyzerPanel);
splitPane.addMouseMotionListener(analyzerPanel);
splitPane.addMouseWheelListener(analyzerPanel);
splitPane.addKeyListener(analyzerPanel);
```